# upgrading magento 1.4x in localhost to magento 1.6x by installing first magento 1.6x, but error?!

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.6, magento

I want to upgrade my magento 1.4x to magento 1.6x by installing the first magento 1.6x n then i copy folder app, skin, media to new installation magento 1.6x and dump the sql database. but error is happened. this is the error..

Error in the file: `“C:\Ampps\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\XmlConnect\sql\xmlconnect_setup\mysql4-install-1.4.0.8.php” - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry ‘3-thumbnail’ for key ‘entity_type_id’`

Please help me guys, how i can fix this problem..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. **Go into phpmyadmin or access mysql daemon via ssh**
2. **Change the name of the table catalog_product_flat_1 to something
   like catalog_product_flat_OLD_1 (just for backup)**
3. **Reindex Product Flat Data in your Magento Admin Panel**